# MySQL INSERT INTO Issues Inside Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm very new to MySQL triggers and procedure code in general, so this is probably a stupid mistake on my part. Here's the code that is not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_to_cart
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SET @status = ‘S’;
SET @user = NEW.user_id;
SET @order = NEW.order_id;

SELECT count(*) INTO @shipped_count 
FROM orders
**WHERE (user_id = @user) AND (order_status = @status);**

SELECT MAX(priority) INTO @max FROM cart;

IF @max = 'NULL' THEN

SET @max = 0;

END IF;

SET @priority = @max + 1;

INSERT INTO cart VALUES (@user, @order, @priority);
**INSERT INTO log VALUES (@count, @user);**

END $$
```

The trigger works as expected until I include the WHERE clause on the SELECT count(*) INTO shipped_count. I can count all the records in the orders table, but when I try to specify certain types of records it does not work.

Also, the bold "INSERT INTO log" also fails for some reason, whereas the exact same syntax works for the INSERT directly above it.

Help! Thanks. I'm clueless.

Comment: It fails for a specific reason. Give us the exact mysql error it causes.

Comment: How do I view the errors? Like I said, completely clueless.

Comment: Manually insert something in `orders` table to force the trigger to run, then use [SHOW ERRORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-errors.html) to display the errors.

Comment: OK. Will do and get back ASAP.

Comment: It says:  #1054 - Unknown column '‘S’' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
SET @status = ‘S’;
```

With:

```
SET @status = 'S';
```

Notice the regular single quotes instead of the rounded single quotes.